# ubi-part man failed with exit extension 10 further information can be found in var/log/syslog help

Tags: system-installation

I cannot be more clear than this:
 [image: Ubuntu installer screenshot]

If I choose "try again" I get stuck here with this error but if I choose "continue anyway":

[image: Ubuntu installer screenshot]

I keep getting these errors.

To be more clear, I can't install Ubuntu because the installer won't let me go any further, Since the error says "you can find more information in `/var/log/syslog`", I am includeing the contents of that file below.

I have an old Compaq cq50 that used to have windows vista at that time I installed Ubuntu 16.04 without any problem but then I upgraded that computer to windows 10 and accidentally erased Ubuntu partition so when I tried to reinstall this message start to show:

> ubi-part man failed with exit extension 10 further information can be found in var/log/syslog

If I continue it keeps saying:

> timezone failed with exit code 2
>
> system console failed with exit code 2 [etc.]

I've tried everything booting options like `nodmraid` and other options and even erasing the entire disk with gparted for a clean install, did not worked, so I'm out of options.

`syslog` file showed this:

```
Nov 23 16:50:19 ubuntu rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="2430" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Nov 23 16:50:19 ubuntu rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Nov 23 16:50:19 ubuntu rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Nov 23 16:50:19 ubuntu rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Nov 23 16:50:19 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Nov 23 16:50:19 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Nov 23 16:50:19 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Nov 23 16:50:19 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-31-generic (buildd@lgw01-58) gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) ) #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:06:14 UTC 2016 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-31.50-generic 4.4.13)

http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]

Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 10' suspended, next retry is Mon Nov 21 22:34:42 2016 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-31-generic (buildd@lgw01-58) (gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) ) #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:06:14 UTC 2016 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-31.50-generic 4.4.13)
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   NSC Geode by NSC
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Cyrix CyrixInstead
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Transmeta GenuineTMx86
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   Transmeta TransmetaCPU
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000]   UMC UMC UMC UMC
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Legacy x87 FPU detected.
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Using 'lazy' FPU context switches.
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Nov 21 22:34:12 ubuntu kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007a08cfff] usable
```